# Select images with vue-select

Tags: vuejs3

How will I do select with [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) in vue 3?

```
<v2-select :options="options" label="title">
   <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">                              
   <img :src="option.url">
  {{ option.url }}
  </template>
</v2-select>
```

Data:

```
 options: [
                    {
                        title: 'Read the Docs',
                        icon: 'fa-book',
                        url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'View on GitHub',
                        icon: 'fa-github',
                        url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'View on NPM',
                        icon: 'fa-database',
                        url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'View Codepen Examples',
                        icon: 'fa-pencil',
                        url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                    }
                ],
    }
```

example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5ni27c?file=src%2FApp.vue,package.json,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

In vue 2 it work, bot in vue 3 dont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slot binding is wrong.

Check the Docs: [Vue - Named Slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots) and [Vue-Select - Slots - option](https://vue-select.org/api/slots.html#option)

This

```
 <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
```

should be written so

```
<template v-slot:option="option">
```

or so (using the shorthand `#`)

```
<template #option="option">
```

Then it works:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

`slot-scope` was [deprecated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots-with-the-slot-scope-Attribute) in Vue2

Answer (score 2):

Using the following version

```json
"vue-select": "^4.0.0-beta.5"
```

And installing like that in `main.js`

```js
import { createApp } from "vue"
import vSelect from "vue-select"

import App from "./App.vue"
const app = createApp(App)
app.component("v-select", vSelect)

app.mount("#app")
```

You can then use the following

```html
<template>
  <v-select :options="options" label="title">
    <template #option="option">
      <span><img :src="option.image" />{{ option.title }}</span>
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [
        {
          title: "Read the Docs",
          image: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/20x20?sig=1",
          url: "https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select",
        },
        {
          title: "View on GitHub",
          image: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/20x20?sig=2",
          url: "https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select",
        },
        {
          title: "View on NPM",
          image: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/20x20?sig=3",
          url: "https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select",
        },
        {
          title: "View Codepen Examples",
          image: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/20x20?sig=4",
          url: "https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

For this kind of result

[image]

---

PS: be careful, some examples in the documentation are indeed not up to date regarding Vue's API, especially `slot-scope` as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74053245/8816585) (not available anymore in Vue3).