# v-if and v-else directives to show created and updated dates

Tags: django, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a django model which stores created and updated date on my front end i have a header called Date in my vue headers i am displaying the created date but i need to display the updated date under the same header when an object is updated. i have same date called **row.updated_date_formatted** if this is none i need to display created_date else i need to display updated date

```
 <template slot="row" slot-scope="{ row, index }">
   <td v-text="row.created_date_formatted"> </td>
  </template>
```

Comment: [`slot-scope` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74053245/8816585) for quite some time already. What did you tried/is not working so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code your logic right in `v-text` parameter value with Vue.
Something like this:

```
<td v-text="row.updated_date_formatted != null ? row.updated_date_formatted : row.created_date_formatted"></td>
```

Or the same with Mustache syntax:

```
<td>{{row.updated_date_formatted != null ? row.updated_date_formatted : row.created_date_formatted}}</td>
```

`v-if` `v-else` is not really necessary in this case.